# Action Listeners

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

How do I use the action listeners that are attached to the buttons. And how would I make it work from a separate class file?

Edit:
This is what i have:

```
import java.awt.*;
```

import java.awt.event.*;

public class Gui {

```
static boolean playerturn = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Frame frame1 =new Frame("TickTacToe - By Fred");
    frame1.setLayout(null);
    frame1.setBounds(250,150,500,500);
    frame1.setVisible(true);
    frame1.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    final Button button11 = new Button("");
    button11.addActionListener(null);

    final Button button12 = new Button("");
    button11.addActionListener(null);

    final Button button13 = new Button("");
    button11.addActionListener(null);

    final Button button21 = new Button("");
    button11.addActionListener(null);

    final Button button22 = new Button("");
    button11.addActionListener(null);

    final Button button23 = new Button("");
    button11.addActionListener(null);

    final Button button31 = new Button("");
    button11.addActionListener(null);

    final Button button32 = new Button("");
    button11.addActionListener(null);

    final Button button33 = new Button("");
    button11.addActionListener(null);


    button11.setBounds(100, 100, 80, 70);
    button12.setBounds(100, 200, 80, 70);
    button13.setBounds(100, 300, 80, 70);
    button21.setBounds(200, 100, 80, 70);
    button22.setBounds(200, 200, 80, 70);
    button23.setBounds(200, 300, 80, 70);
    button31.setBounds(300, 100, 80, 70);
    button32.setBounds(300, 200, 80, 70);
    button33.setBounds(300, 300, 80, 70);

    frame1.add(button11); 
    frame1.add(button12); 
    frame1.add(button13); 
    frame1.add(button21); 
    frame1.add(button22); 
    frame1.add(button23); 
    frame1.add(button31); 
    frame1.add(button32);
    frame1.add(button33); 
}}
```

What i need is someway of being able to utilize the listeners.

Comment: Please give the details of your specific problem.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And how would i make it work form a different class file?

Import it, if you need to, and then create an instance of it.

> how to use the action listeners that are attached to the buttons

Place the logic that you'd like to be executed within the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method of the `ActionListener` class (or subclass).

For more information, see [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).

Comment: Is there any neater way to split it up?

Comment: @user1489906, I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: @user1489906: we've asked for the details of your problem, without which no one can give you a good answer, but you've yet to reply. Why?

Comment: This answer provides enough of information for Someone with a basic knowledge of Programming, to proceed. +1