# How can I link a new function in my GUI Jbutton?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

```
bhome = new JButton("Home");
bhome.setFont(font);
bhome.setFocusPainted(false);
bhome.setSize(100, 25);
bhome.setLocation(70, 30);
bhome.addActionListener(this);
panel.add(bhome);
```

This is my JButton, how can I link a new function to it?
By function, I mean when you click the Home button, it directs you to the Homepage of the system/program.

Comment: Call your functions from the ActionListener! Also provide proper(complete relevant) code. You code makes no sense at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Action Listeners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254188/action-listeners)

Answer (score 1):

```
JButton bhome = new JButton("Home");
bhome.addActionListener(new HomeListener());

class HomeListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // Do whatever you want to do
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by function, you mean a segment of code to be executed upon clicking the button, you must write an ActionListener for the button.

[Here's an example.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Basically, you define the action listener and stick what code you want executed inside the listener's actionPerformed method.

Answer (score 0):

```
btnYourButton= new JButton("Home");
btnYourButton.setFont(font);
btnYourButton.setFocusPainted(false);
btnYourButton.setSize(100, 25);
btnYourButton.setLocation(70, 30);
panel.add(btnYourButton);
btnYourButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    btnYourButton_actionPerformed(e);
  }
});
// out side of the method where you declared your button
void btnYourButton_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       //Your code goes here
}
```

Easiest and higher understandability